# Add Margin with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add some space between some "bubble speech".

I have a demo [here](http://jsbin.com/uLuvaWU/7)

I thought that adding a margin-bottom will work, but it doesn't.

Any one could help me with this. Thanks in advance

```
.quote_speech a.more{
    margin-left: 160px;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    background: #636363;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    top:10px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use margin-bottom, here is working example, just **copy** and **paste**

```
.quote_speech a.more{
    margin-left: 160px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    background: #636363;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    top:10px;

}
```

Comment: It actually works. With the difference that I didn't have the inline-block in the display option

Comment: It works. I only needed to remove the top:10px option

Comment: @Diego: This is a basic HTML concept. Please try to understand them instead of just copying/pasting.

Answer (score 4):

All of these answers are ignoring *one simple issue* that is causing your margin to not work as you expect.

Your css includes a `top:10px` for the `a.more` link. Remove that, and your margin starts working properly.

As a side-note - you've got tons of redundant / non-necessary css in there.  `display: inline` is default for an a element, `position: relative` is not necessary unless you're doing some positioning inside of the a element, `clear: both` is not necessary because you're not floating anything at all....

Finally, the best way IMHO to get margin-bottom to be responsive is to change to `display:inline-block` for the a element, like so:

```
.quote_speech a.more {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #636363;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: 160px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't. I still need a spece between the Read More and the Bubble. I have the top:10px because I need space betweem the Copmany Name and the Read More

Comment: @Diego - made an edit to show that inline-block gives you what you want.

Comment: @cale_b- here is the new [version](http://jsbin.com/uLuvaWU/9). with David Khasikyan  solution. I guess you're right with the "you've got tons of redundant / non-necessary css " Not a CSS Guru, going to check your solution

Comment: @Diego - it's almost working.  Just need to remove the `top:10px`.

Comment: @cale_b- could you explain me why I need to remove the 10px? Want to know the real cause.

Comment: You should remove anything that doesn't serve a specific purpose.  What purpose do you have in having top: 10px? None, I contend, since you actually want it to be *higher*, not lower, and top: 10px is pusing it down.

Answer (score 1):

Simple :-D

Change `display:inline;` to `display:inline-block;` in class `.more`.

Now you can mess with the margins, height, and whatever!

Comment: @cale_b sorry didn't see your response. +1 for ya

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin-top` to `<div class="bubble">`below the "Read More" button.

You could also add `margin-bottom`to `div class="quote_speech">`.

```
.bubble {
    ...
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

OR

```
.quote_speech {
    ...
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this code to `.quote_speech`:

```
.quote_speech {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add `margin-top` to `.bubble`

```
   .bubble {
    margin-top: 25px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `paddin-buttom:15px;` in your quote_speech class.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the css for the more link:

```
.quote_speech a.more{
    margin-left: 160px;
    display:block;
    background: #636363;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 3px 10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin-bottom:3%;
}
```

and it all worked as expected.

http://jsbin.com/uLuvaWU/17/

Answer (score 0):

Your code are setting `margin-bottom: 0px`, this is the root of the problem. Set it do 25px and the problem is solved.

```
.quote_speech {
    width: 20em;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    bottom: -15px;
    right: 170px;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: 75px;
}
```

After all, when you set 0 to some value, don't place `px`, let it like this: `margin-bottom: 0`.